# Objective-C SpriteKit – How to make a circle of buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, spritekit

I have some code in a project already, but I'd like to change it up a bit. Currently, my code creates an empty node called `_buttonLayer` and then create some buttons to add to it. My buttons start from the top-left corner of the `_buttonLayer` and then get added all the way to the bottom-right corner.

```
// Set up button layer.
_buttonLayer = [SKNode node];
_buttonLayer.position = CGPointMake(_centerOfScreen.x - (_buttonSize.width * 1.5) - 5.0,
                                    self.size.height - ((self.size.height * 0.375) + (_buttonSize.height) - 50.0) + 5.0);
[self addChild:_buttonLayer];


// Set up button array.
_buttonArray = [NSMutableArray array];


// Add some buttons.
for (char row = 0; row < 4; row++) {
    for (char col = 0; col < 4; col++) {

        // Buttons.
        SKSpriteNode *button = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"LightGreyButton"];
        button.name = @"LightGreyButton"; // Initially set it to grey, because they all start off that way.
        button.size = _buttonSize;
        button.position = CGPointMake(2.0 + ((button.size.width + 3.0) * col),
                                      -(2.0 + ((button.size.height + 3.0) * row)));
        [_buttonLayer addChild:button];
        [_buttonArray addObject:button];

    }
}
```

So what I need to do now is create the buttons in a circle – instead of in a square. I'd like to somehow add the buttons into an outline of a circle, and then take the whole `_buttonLayer` and rotate it. Of course, the way I have it right now, it rotates on the top-left corner of the square. I want the middle of the circle to rotate.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a [cross-network post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33529255/objective-c-spritekit-how-to-make-circle-of-buttons)

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate the entire _buttonLayer if you make it a SKSpriteNode a subclass of SKNode. You will have access to the default anchorPoint property that is already set in the middle of the SKSpriteNode object. (0.5,0.5) is the center. You will want to set its color property to clearColor so you have the same appearance as you would with using a SKNode. You will have access to the zRotation property of SKNode on your SKSpriteNode as well. That is one way of doing it.

It seems like two questions really? It might be better breaking them up. One for laying buttons out in a circle and the other for rotation. Hope that helps?

Comment: Thanks for your help, @Robert, but someone on stackoverflow.com answered my problem. The link is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33529255/objective-c-spritekit-how-to-make-circle-of-buttons/33531193#33531193).